# Unable to access dynamoDb data from cli with non key attributes

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

I have a table in aws dynamodb which I am trying to access using aws-cli

I need to access the documents using non key attributes.

Below are the commands which I have tried :

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name aixm_cycle_info --filter-expression "mapAttr. queriedField = :isLatest" --expression-attribute-values '{ ":isLatest" : { "S": "true" }}'

aws dynamodb query --table-name aixm_cycle_info --key-condition-expression "isLatest=:isLatest" --expression-attribute-values "{ :isLatest : { BOOL: true}}"
```

A document in my database looks like this :

```
{
  "bucket": "nm-data",
  "cycleId": "1910.190927",
  "filesGenerated": [
    "abc.BASELINE.gz",
    "cdf.gz",
    "xyz.gz",
  ],
  "generatedDate": "2019-09-27T13:42:52.166Z",
  "id": "f9110c95-39f6-4a8f-b497-0b6382a9bf2f",
  "isLatest": "false",
  "region": "US_EAST_2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name aixm_cycle_info --filter-expression "mapAttr.queriedField = :isLatest" --expression-attribute-values '{ ":isLatest" : { "S": "true" }}'
```

There is an extra space after mapAttr

Also if you are querying by non key fields, you can only use scan (which will read all items, line by line).

If you want the query to be efficient, add an index and use "query" on it.